# How to add three numbers using safemath?

Tags: solidity, uint256, math, safemath

I know this might sound obvious but in solidity you can never be too sure.

Let us say I have three numbers 5, 7 and 8. Can I add them like so:

```
using SafeMath for uint256;

5.add(7.add(8));
// or even like so
5.add(7).add(8);
// or
5.add(7 + 8);
```

Is there any risk(of overflow or anything else) of using either?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing `5.add(7)` is a syntax sugar for `add(5, 7)`.

So first expression `5.add(7.add(8))` is `add(5, add(7, 8))` and the second one `5.add(7).add(8)` is `add(add(5, 7), 8)`.

In the particular case of SafeMath's `add` both expression will arrive at the same result. For other functions like `sub` and `div` make sure they are in the correct order.

The last expression `5.add(7 + 8)` isn't like the others, since `7 + 8` is never checked for overflow. Here it doesn't matter because they are small numbers, but if you used variables it might break.